# Set Parent Validator from Child Component [Angular]

Tags: angular, forms, components

How can I set the validator of a parent form field from an action of the child component. I tried this (and some other ways) so far but without success.

After I go into the name field and enter something and delete it I can see the error message. But it has to show it immediately.

```
   // PARENT
     
   constructor(...) {
        this.parentForm = new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl('')
        });
    }
     
    isBMAdded: boolean;
     
    receiveDataFromChild($event) {
        this.isBMAdded = $event;
        if (this.isBMAdded) {
            this.parentForm.get('name').setValidators([Validators.required]);
        } else {
            this.parentForm.get('name').setValidators([]);
        }
    }
     
    // PARENT Template
     
    <child-component (setBM)="receiveDataFromChild($event)"></child-component>
     

    <input formControlName="name"
               type="number"
               [invalid]="myForm.get('name').invalid">
            <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.get('name').invalid">
                Name is required
            </mat-error>
     </input>

    // CHILD
     
    @Output()
    isBMAdded = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
     
    setBM(): void {
        this.isBMAdded.emit(true);
    }
     
    // CHILD Template
    <input 
          (input)="setSowingTechnologyForm()"
          type="number">
    </input>
```

Comment: If possible make use of` ```Subject / BehaviorSubject``` from ```rxjs``` operators, if you need to notify the parent on change of some value or on some action.

Comment: There seems to be errors in your sample of code. In the child component the output is named isBMAdded. But in the parent component you bind an Output named setBM.